# Does javascript _.where() function not allow spaces in the string?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to use _.where to look through this large json mapping file. I have used it before but the search terms never contained spaces and the function worked well. Now I am using search terms that have spaces and it never brings back any matches. Here is a segment of code with an example entityName (the search term).

```
   entityName = "HEMTT WRECKER M984A1 MK19";
    alert("entityName2: " + entityName);
    entityMap = _.where(cdpeConfig.oobEntityMap, { "obs name" :entityName});
    alert("entityMap: " + entityMap);
```

Inside of the oobEntityMap there are json elements the above entityName should match with the following:

```
{
"obs name":"HEMTT WRECKER M984A1 MK19",
"edcss name":"M977_HEMTT_CARGO",
"mapping type":"skos:relatedMatch",
"obs dis enum":"1:2:225:7:19:3:2",
"edcss dis enum":"1:0:225:9:19:1:0"
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in standalone code? We don't know what is in `cdpeConfig.oobEntityMap`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what's in cdpeConfig.oobEntityMap? Preferably with some of the results you think `_.where` should be finding

Comment: Halcyon and @rwacarter does the edit help

Comment: @SketchyTurtle Does it work if you change the search to `{ "edcss name" :"M977_HEMTT_CARGO"}`? This would check if it is the spaces that are the problem, which I would be very surprised if they were.

Comment: @rwacarter yes it does work like that, it doesn't seem to like the spaces for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not have a _.where() function.  Underscore does have this function, which is probably what your using.

http://underscorejs.org/#where

It does allow for spaces.

```
var stuff = [
    {"Bilbo Baggins" : "Little Hobbit"},  
    {"Gandalf Grey" : "Tall Wizard"}
];

var foo = _.where(stuff, {"Bilbo Baggins" : "Little Hobbit"}); 
console.log(foo);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/av3rhxp9/

Try seeing if cdpeConfig.oobEntityMap that your passing is actually an object or an array and that is not undefined or empty. 
.

Comment: you were right that I should double check my oobEntityMap it turned out that it wasn't on the vm that I am using, so it was trying to pull at nothing

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `_.filter` instead of `_.where`, to see if that makes any difference:

```
entityMap = _.filter(cdpeConfig.oobEntityMap, function(obj){ 
     return obj["obs name"].match(/HEMTT WRECKER M984A1 MK19/);
});
```

Comment: @SketchyTurtle how about replacing what's in `match` to `/HEMTT.WRECKER.M984A1.MK19/` (use full stops instead of spaces)

Comment: still not getting anything back